# Presto map(varchar,varchar) : How to get all the possible keys for it?

Tags: presto

I am trying to search a column having the data type map(varchar,varchar). Now one way to access the column is to use this structure, name_of_column['**key**'], which will give the value for that key. But I want to know what are possible **keys** and then apply group by and other operations based on those **keys**.

I tried searching on the internet but was not able to find appropriate solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presto offers [`map_keys`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/map.html) function for that:

```
presto> select map_keys(map(array['alice'], array['has a cat']));
  _col0
---------
 [alice]
(1 row)
```

Comment: This returns an array of the keys for each row. How can I combine all the results as its own column?